# local variable '?' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am new to Python and programming in general. I would like to know how to get rid of this compile error

```
def health_risk(activity_level, is_smoker):
    """Counts the aliveness of a person"""  
    alive = "alive?" or "sedentary"
    very_low = "low" or "very low"
    active = "active" or "very active"    
    if (activity_level in alive) and is_smoker is True:
        xer = "extreme" 
    elif (activity_level in active) and is_smoker is True:
        xer = "medium"    
    elif (activity_level == alive) and (is_smoker is False):
        xer = "high"     
    elif (activity_level == very_low) and (is_smoker is False):
        xer = "medium"  
    elif activity_level == active and is_smoker is False:
        xer = "low"          
    return xer
level = health_risk('low', True)
print(level)
```

Thanks for the help and this is my first post, thanks.

Comment: Your `if` statements don't cover all possibilities so it is possible to never assign to `xer`. Also, you will find that your class attributes don't have the values you think they do (`alive` is just `"alive?"` because `"alive?"` is a non-empty string and therefore truthy, so the second part of the `or` is not considered).

Comment: Your function call does not satisfy any of the `if` statements, therefore `return xer` will not work

Comment: As an aside, what do you think you are doing with this line: `alive = "alive?" or "sedentary"`

Answer (score 0):

Revise your variable statements to be assigned to lists.

```
alive = ["alive", "sedentary"]
very_low = ["low", "very low"]
active = ["active", "very active"]
```

Replace all `==` with `in`,

Include the missing `elif` statement.

```
elif (activity_level in very_low) and (is_smoker is True):
    xer = "high" # or medium or whatever
```

note: to reduce redundancy, you could just put `and is_smoker` if it's `True` and `and not is_smoker` if it's `False`.